# Springs @Autowiring functionality Along with Mocking

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, mockito, junit4

Issue : 
I have a class A

```
class A {

      @Autowired
      EdocumentDAO eDocumentDAO;

      public void createDocument(DocumentType docType)
      {
            String DocID= saveIndocRepo();//To be Mocked
            docType.setID(DocID);

            isSaved = eDocumentDAO.save()//Autowired

      }
      private String saveIndocRepo()
      {
          //Code to save in Repo in another platform and return the DOC_ID
      }


}
```

My A_Test class

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-beans.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class A_test {

        A a = Mockito.spy(new A());

        Mockito.doReturn("DOC_ID").when(a).saveIndocRepo();
        a.createDocument(docType);      
}
```

**Requirement** : 
I have method `saveIndocRepo()` which interacts with the external service and save the document in their repo. So this needs to be mocked.

which is called in the `createDocument()` and a the mocked value should be returned.After the DocID is received the other Document Details are saved into the DB (for which I have configured a Derby In-memory DB). The EdocumentDAO works on the Autowiring which is instantiated by the springs.

**Issue**:
When I try to mock the method(saveInDocRepo) its Mocked successfully but the Autowiring fails. Which results in the JUnit failure.
When I remove the mocking then the Autowiring is executing perfectly.

Is there anything that I am missing. Or is my approach not correct.
Experts - Please advise an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, for you help.

Solution:

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:test-beans.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")

@Spy
@InjectMocks
A a = new A();

@Autowired
@Spy
EdocumentDAO eDocumentDAO;
class A_test {

        Mockito.doReturn("DOC_ID").when(a).saveIndocRepo();
        a.createDocument(docType);      
}
```

Now when the createDocument() method is called, the saveInDocRepo() is mocked to return "DOC_ID" and the eDocumentDAO.save() works perfectly.
Its @Spy which is used for partial mocking, saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Mock an Interface and not the Class itself.
Create an Interface with the public methods of the Class to Mock.

In your example above, you are Spying on `A`, but `A` depends on `EdocumentDAO`. You have to Mock this Class too.

```
@Mock
EdocumentDAO edocumentDAOMock;
```

or, my favorite way with Spring since you can implement a mock behavior:

```
@Bean
private EdocumentDAO getEdocumentDAOMock() {
    return mock(EdocumentDAO.class);
}
```

Also, since you are using Spring, you can't use `new A()`, you have to use Spring to instantiate a Bean, otherwise the autowired annotation won't work.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. I have tried mocking the EDocumentDAO, when I mock I loose the save functionality, which means that the save() wouldn't work. For which I have using the derby DB.

Comment: You should isolate your tests. Have a test for the DAO, and a test for the document creator. So indeed, the save method should not work in your test, and it's a good practice it does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shorthand injection of mockito and not rely on Spring on this one :

```
class ATest {
    @Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
    @Mock EdocumentDAO dao;
    @InjectMocks A a;

    @Test
    public void the_test() {
        doReturn("DOC_ID").when(dao).saveIndocRepo();
        a.createDocument(docType);
    }
}
```

*Note this is pseudo code, as I cannot use an IDE right now*

Comment: Thanks Brice for the quick response, I tried creating as per your suggestion. But Unfotunately got this error "Argument passed to when() is not a mock!" as the instance is not of type Mock. Also that I am testing the DAO functionality with a IN-Memory derby db. Will Mocking the DAO workout?

Comment: Yeah copy paste from your question's code, it shouldn't be `a` but `dao` (which is the actual mock). I updated the answer.